# Modify the value before display in TableView javafx

Tags: java, javafx, view, tree

Controller code

```
@Override

public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    try {
            Connection con = db.connect();

            list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("Select * from Student");
            while (rs.next()) {
                list.add(new Student(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2),new java.util.Date(rs.getDate(3).getTime()) ));

            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DisplayAllStudentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    studentID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("studentID"));

    name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

    admissionDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("admissionDate"))

    tableView.setItems(null);

    tableView.setItems(list);
```

I want to do some operation on data before display in table view

LIKE  SWING

```
tableRow[3] = DateConverter.toString(c.getAdmissionDate());
```

In swing i do like this and it worked perfectly.

but don't know how to do operation on tableview javafx.

Comment: Tell us what is current behavior and what is the desired outcome you want to implement?

Comment: i want to perform some operation on database value and then display in treeview table  example database value in field 1 is : 100 and i want to change value to 200 (this change not save in database/ temporary change value ) then display the new modify value in treetable.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to add a [CellFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#cellFactoryProperty%28%29) to the given column (don't mix with [CellValueFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#cellValueFactoryProperty%28%29)). You don't mention what exactly you want to do with what data but if you want to format date to string in your own way you can write a class like:

```
public class LocalDateCellFactory<T> implements Callback<TableColumn<T, LocalDate>, TableCell<T, LocalDate>> {

    @Override
    public TableCell<T, LocalDate> call(TableColumn<T, LocalDate> col) {
        return new TableCell<T, LocalDate>() {

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if ((item == null) || empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    return;
                }

                setText(item.format(...yourOwnFormat...));
            }

        };
    }

}
```

...and then just use it anywhere you want to display date in a tableview:

```
admissionDate.setCellFactory(new LocalDateCellFactory<>());
```

Comment: Suppose I have two table column 1 for lastBillPayed date and another for amount . (amount on the basic of current Date MINUS  lastBillPayed date ) Then assign total calculate amount on second feild

Comment: This sounds like a new question rather than a comment to the original one. In that case, please, accept the answer and post this as a new question. (It's hard to post code examples in comments). And when you do so, try to specify the problem more precisely, please. I understand what you want to achieve, but I don't quite understand, what the problem is? Post an example code and tell us, where you got stuck and what doesn't work so we can help.

Comment: tomorrow please  help me check my this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551764/tableview-how-to-get-and-set-value-in-column